# What are some ways to make caramel thin?

Tags: baking, bread, sauce, sugar, caramel

I'm kind of starting off with the culinary world and one of the dishes i'll be making soon is French toast with caramelized strawberries.

However i'd like to know how to make caramel thin, because i'll be drizzling it over the dish and the strawberries, many thanks ^^

Comment: That sounds like you need a recipe for caramel *sauce*. Some such recipes start by melting caramel, and normally add dairy.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. I assume that you are asking for a caramel which remains thin, which is a question that has been asked before - on our site, we insist that all the answers to a given topic are found under one question, instead everybody having to hunt it down in multiple places, that's why we close duplicates. If you are so new to caramel that you don't know how it is drizzled before solidifying: the newly made caramel is always liquid before it cools and hardens, so just follow your recipe and all be well. Actually, following a recipe for the first case is also a good idea.

Comment: Also, kitchen terms seem to have tripped you up here: the term "caramelized strawberries" is not associated with "strawberries plus caramel", it invokes the picture of you roasting strawberries in a pan until their surface turns brown, optionally with a very little sugar added at the end. Might be important if you start looking for recipes and the query [caramelized strawberries] doesn't find what you wanted.